# How can I add custom error message and remove the error message thrown by Site.login in visualforce page?

Tags: apex, visualforce, error-messages, login-errors, adderror

How can I add custom error message and remove the error message thrown by Site.login in visualforce page?

Im having trouble removing the error message thrown by Site.login that says "Error: Your login attempt has failed. Make sure the username and password are correct."

I need to replace it to another custom error message. I used apex messages but still the Site.login error occurs.

**Class:**

```
private PageReference getLoginDetails() {
    String startUrl = System.currentPageReference().getParameters().get('startURL');
    //return Site.login(username,password, OrganizationSettings__c.getInstance().PortalEmailURL__c +'/'+'dashboard'); 
 // return Site.login(username,password, startUrl);
     PageReference pr = Site.login(username,password, startUrl);
    if(pr == null ){ 
      //return null;
       ApexPages.addmessage(new ApexPages.message(ApexPages.severity.Info, '* You\'ve entered an incorrect username and/or password. Please re-enter your log-in information.'));
    }
        return pr;

}
```

**VF Page:**

```
<!--** START // DISPLAY ERROR MSG**-->
<apex:pageBlock >
    <apex:outputPanel styleClass="errorMsg"><apex:pageMessages id="showmsg"></apex:pageMessages></apex:outputPanel> 
</apex:pageBlock>
<!--** END // DISPLAY ERROR MSG**-->
```

**Output:**

> Error: Your login attempt has failed. Make sure the username and
>   password are correct.
>   You've entered an incorrect username and/or password. Please re-enter your log-in information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its frustrating that the messages that `apex:pageMessages` presents can't be cleared out and replaced. So you are stuck with *not* including that tag in your page and instead using your own logic and the [apex:pageMessage](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_pageMessage.htm) tag:

```
<apex:pageMessage summary="You have ..." severity="warning" rendered="{! error }"/>
```

where you define and set an `error` property in yourcontroller:

```
public Boolean error {get; set;}

    ...
    error = pr == null;
    ...
```